# VBA Excel Delete Table rows and shift up, not entire row

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have a situation just like this image here: 
[image: Screenshot]

How do I delete only the cells denoted as red and shift the below cells up?

There is a table below and that should not get affected. Can some one help?

Thanks

Jeevan

Comment: Clear the contents, sort and resize the table.

Comment: I can't clear the contents, nor sort. It is full of data, I just erased the data in those tables just for the screenshot.

Comment: I have copied the content of one table in a temporary location, deleted that table, deleted those rows and then created the deleted table.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the cells in the sheet and the table will be adjusted:

`Range("B12:C12").Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Comment: This throws an error if there are other table(s) to either side of the table from which you're wanting to remove rows, whose rows would also be affected. "Run-time error '1004': This won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet."

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found by recording a macro to delete a table row.
This example is from a for loop but can be modified to work however.
Select a cell in the table row you want to delete
Remember the table row is not the same as  the worksheet row. in this case i have a blank row above my table and the header row so -2

```
    Cells(i, 4).Select 
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows(i - 2).Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
ListObject("TableName").ListRows(RowIndex).Delete
```

And add an empty row to the bottom.

```
ListObject("TableName").ListRows.Add
```

Comment: I tried the delete, but this error appears "This operation is not allowed. The operation is attempting to shift cells in a table on your worksheet."

Comment: You could try to convert it to range, delete the row and convert it back to a table.